# Set class' bool permanently from outside the class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying use a class (second in code below) to change a boolean in another class (first one in code below) to true through a switch statement. I think the problem is once the program exits the switch scope, the boolean doesn't stay to it's changed value but I'm not sure why.

```
//first class 
public bool HasStrike
        {
            get { return hasStrike; }
            set
            {
                if (value == true)
                {
                    Debug.Log("HasStrike set to true");
                    hasStrike = value;
                }
                else if (value == false)
                {
                    Debug.Log("hasStrike set to false");
                    hasStrike = value;
                }

            }

        }

public void Strike()
        {
            if (chance[1] >= 10)
            {
                this.HasStrike = true;
                chance[1] = 10;
            }
        }
```

```
//second class
 IEnumerator WaitforFallingPins()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);
        gameStatus.frame[gameStatus.currentFrame].Strike();
        NextChance(ref gameStatus.frame[gameStatus.currentFrame]);
    }

 void NextChance(ref GameStatus.frame currentFrame)
    {
        switch (gameStatus.currentChance)
        {
            case 1:
              if (currentFrame.hasStrike)
                {
                    bowlingSet.SetAllPins();
                    Debug.Log("Strike has happened");
                    break;
                }

                else 
                {
                    Debug.Log("this is not a strike");
                    gameStatus.currentChance += 1;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

In the switch statement, it always goes to the else statement even though it was set to true and I got the debug.log for true printed from the set property.

For more context: This is a bowling game. Gamestatus is the game manager script that has a array of frames and each frame has HasStrike and Strike(). Gamestatus keeps track of what frame we are in and what chance (each time you roll the ball) we are in. After pins are hit, NextChance happens so that the frame can decide if it had a strike or not. The frame class is also inside the gamestatus class.

Comment: It is not completely clear why this issue is occurring from your code. Is the condition `if (chance[1] >= 10)` ever met? When is the coroutine `WaitforFallingPins` called? And how often?

Comment: check with alt+f12 or right click + find all references to the `HasStrike` property to check if it could be changed somewhere else. I would do the same for the `hasStrike` variable in case it might be public, or changed within the class somewhere else

Comment: Make sure when calling `WaitforFallingPins` you call it as `StartCouroutine(WaitforFallingPins())`. I recently had the same issue, so might be worth checking.

Comment: I inserted a missing `"` which I guess was just a typo here in your question

Comment: You could btw make the property a bit simpler: `set { Debug.Log($"{nameof(HasStrike)} set to {value}"); hasStrike = value; }` ;) Also why using a `switch` if you cover only one single case anyway?